# Gridview Refresh Problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I have a gridview in an asp.net page, and get the data by binding it to a SQL Server Table, I use C# and Stored Procedure in SQL server to bind the data. every thing works fine,except when I Delete multiple rows by using Stored Procedure, the gridview still shows the old data. actually I have couple of text boxes that the user can enter the data and an asp button,as soon as user click the button, in code behind I call the Stored procedure and delete the data.

How could I Reload / Refresh the page? after deleting the rows?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a datasource control (you supplied the datasourceid property), you have to call `Grid.DataBind()`.

If you use the DataSource property of the grid, you have to reload the data source into that property from the database and call `DataBind()`.

Comment: `Grid.DataBind()` is not available

Comment: Replace "Grid" with the ID of the Grid, but if that is not available, are you in a static method?

Comment: That wasn't my problem. I was using `DataGridView` control instead this discussion is over `GridView`

Answer (score 3):

Just rebind your data to the gridview with another call to the database.

```
GridView1.DataSource = GetData();  //get your data with your original stored proc
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could delete the rows in your datasource and rebind it to the grid to avoid retrieving data from the database again.